# until loop with if statements

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am stuck on a part and i don't understand why, let me paste my code:

```
    local correctId=false
    echo $ticketMessage
    read deviceId

     until [[ $deviceId =~ [0-9]+ && correctId = true ]]; do

      if [ ! -e $baseDevicesPath"/$deviceId" ]; then
       echo $deviceError
       correctId=false
      else
       correctId=true
      fi

     if [[ ! $deviceId =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
       echo $ticketMessage
     fi

      read deviceId
     done

    echo "I DONT COME HERE?"
```

if both deviceId and correctId are true, it should exit the until loop and go further? but it doesn't, any idea what i do wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You just have a simple typo. you are missing the `$` in front of correctID in your condition:

```
local correctId=false
echo $ticketMessage
read deviceId

 until [[ $deviceId =~ [0-9]+ && $correctId = true ]]; do

  if [ ! -e $baseDevicesPath"/$deviceId" ]; then
   echo $deviceError
   correctId=false
  else
   correctId=true
  fi

 if [[ ! $deviceId =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
   echo $ticketMessage
 fi

  read deviceId
 done

echo "NOW YOU WILL END HERE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change correctId into $correctId (of ${correctId}).
I would add double quotes:

```
local correctId="false"
echo ${ticketMessage}
read deviceId

until [[ $deviceId =~ [0-9]+ && "${correctId}" = "true" ]]; do

  if [ ! -e "${baseDevicesPath}/${deviceId}" ]; then
   echo ${deviceError}
   correctId="false"
  else
   correctId="true"
  fi

 if [[ ! "${deviceId}" =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
   echo ${ticketMessage}
 fi

  read deviceId
 done

echo "Do you come here?"
```

Comment: strictly speaking, double quotes are not required in `[[ ]]` -- bash doesn't do word splitting there ([ref](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b)). Single brackets, you do require variables to be quoted (unless you want the side effects)

Answer (score 0):

here is a bit more readable solution

```
function findDevice {
echo $ticketMessage;
read deviceId;

while true; do
    local errorMessage;
    if [[ $deviceId =~ [0-9]+ ]]; then
        if [ -e $baseDevicesPath"/$deviceId" ]; then
            #valid input, breaking the loop
            break;              
        fi
        errorMessage=$deviceError;
    else
        errorMessage=$ticketMessage;
    fi
    echo $errorMessage;
    read deviceId;
done
}
```